# Page Update issue

Tags: asp.net

I have created an update button on a page and everything is going in right manner but when I update the date the update record do not changes while pressing update button when rather than refreshing the page, means when I refresh the page then page contents are updated.
what should i do in this matter?

Comment: you need to use ajax to update page contents without refreshing the entire page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Could use ajax update panel to update the partial page ...

Here is sample, how to use the update panel using ajax...

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" > 
 <head runat="server"> 
 <title>Illustrating Partial Page Rendering using ASP.NET Ajax</title> 
 </head> 
    <body> 
    <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
     <div> 
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"> 
     </asp:ScriptManager> 
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"> 
       <ContentTemplate> 
         <table> 
          <tr> 
           <td><asp:Label ID="lblTime" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td>   
          </tr> 
         <tr> 
         <td> 
          <asp:Button ID="btnShow" runat="server" Text="Show Current Time" OnClick="btnShowTime_Click" /> 
        </td> 
       </tr>            
      </table> 
     </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>         
 </div> 
</form>
```

The Click Event Handler for the Button

The click event handler for the Button control is responsible for updating the current time in the Label control. Here's how you define the click handler for the Button control:

```
using System; 
namespace AjaxTest 
{ 
 public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
 { 

      protected void btnShowTime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
      { 
         lblTime.Text = "The Current Time is: "+DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(); 
      } 

      protected void btnShowTime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          lblTime.Text = "The Current Time is: "+DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
      }

  }
}
```

pls take look at this link for [more info](http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=702)

i hope it will helps you